# Is it possible to cast Unity GameObject to ScriptableObject class type?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I have created **scriptable** object custom class Card:

```cs
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Card", menuName = "Card")]
public class Card : ScriptableObject
{
    public new string name;
    public string Description;
    public Sprite HeroImage;
    public int Attack;
    public int Health;
    public int XCoord;
    public int YCoord;
}
```

I have added plenty of such objects through Unity Editor, and instanced such objects as **GameObjects** on 2d Canvas:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    GameObject go = Instantiate(CardPrefabTemplate, new Vector3(x_delt, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    go.transform.SetParent(MPlayerOpenedCards.transform, false);
    go.gameObject.name = "CardUIPrefabOpened" + i;
    x_delt += (int)(CardPrefabTemplBackgrRect.rect.width * CardPrefabTemplateBackground.localScale.x) + x_card_margin;
}
```

After Raycast by mouse click I get current clicked Card **GameObject**:

```cs
GameObject RaycastOpenedCard(string prefabName)
{
    //Set up the new Pointer Event
    m_PointerEventData = new PointerEventData(m_EventSystem);
    //Set the Pointer Event Position to that of the mouse position
    m_PointerEventData.position = Input.mousePosition;
    //Create a list of Raycast Results
    List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();
    //Raycast using the Graphics Raycaster and mouse click position
    m_Raycaster.Raycast(m_PointerEventData, results);

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        foreach (RaycastResult result in results)
        {
            if (result.gameObject.transform.parent != null && Regex.IsMatch(result.gameObject.transform.parent.name, prefabName))
            {
                Debug.Log("Hit " + result.gameObject.transform.parent.name);
                return result.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

In other part of program, I have `List<Card> ActiveCards` list and I am not able to **cast** Raycasted **GameObject** to scriptableobject class **Card**:

```cs
GameObject g = RaycastOpenedCard("CardUIPrefabOpened");
if (g != null)
{
    if (ActiveCards != null && ActiveCards.Count < 5)
    {
        Mplayer.ActiveCards.Add(g.GetComponent<Card>());
    }
}
```

Is it possible to cast Unity **GameObject** to **ScriptableObject** class type?

Error:

> ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component 'Card' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface.
>       UnityEngine.GameObject.GetComponent[T] () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/GameObject.bindings.cs:28)
>       BoardManager.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/BoardManager.cs:202)

Comment: *`Is it possible to cast Unity GameObject to ScriptableObject class type?`* No. That doesn't make any sense based on your error ether. Its telling you that you're trying to `GetComponent` on a Type that is not a MonoBehaviour. ScriptableObjects are *assets* (like text files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, no, it's not possible to cast a `GameObject` to `ScriptableObject`, nor the opposite for that matter. This is because `GameObject` doesn't inherit from `ScriptableObject` and neither does `ScriptableObject` from `GameObject`. Both of them directly inherit from `Object` however.

The reason the line `GameObject go = Instantiate(CardPrefabTemplate, new Vector3(x_delt, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;` is because `Instantiate` that takes an `Object` as argument and that clones it, returning an `Object`. A `ScriptableObject` is an `Object` so that works. And you can cast an `Object` to an `GameObject` so that works too. But that doesn't achieve much as the only thing you'll keep by doing that is the `Object` part, so in your example, `Object.name`.

Now the reason `GetComponent` fails is because it can only look for a `MonoBehaviour`, which a `ScriptableObject` (Card) isn't. `MonoBehaviour` also inherit from `Object` a some point by the way.

So the real question is what were you trying to achieve in the first place ?

Comment: *`Now the reason GetComponent fails is because it can only look for a MonoBehaviour`* There are non-MonoBehaviour components, such as Transform, MeshRenderer, Sprite, and so on. The difference is that you (as a developer) can't create objects that derive directly from `Component`, only `MonoBehaviour`, but that doesn't preclude their existence. You can also pass in an `interface` and it works Just Fine (though it can only find Components that implement that interface).

Comment: Additionally, just because `Instantiate` takes in an `Object` and casts it to a `GameObject` doesn't always "work" (the thing-to-instantiate must have been a GameObject beforehand). If you pass in a Transform, you'll get a Transform back out (because the specific implementation is Generic: `public static T Instantiate(T original);`) and if you try to `as` it to a GameObject, you'll get an InvalidClassCastException.